# MapBox: Initializing the LocationEngineCallback in a foreground service

Tags: java, mapbox, mapbox-android

The idea is that I want to keep track on the user's location each 10 seconds as requesting new Location updates. For this purpose I have a foreground service,

```
public class LocationService extends Service{
 ...
}
```

where I initialize request options, but I need also to initialize the callback. In the documentation says that a private class must be defined, in order to avoid memory leaks. However, I can't use it, since it wants an activity and not a service class as a parameter in the following code:

```
private final WeakReference<LocationChangeListeningActivity> activityWeakReference;

LocationChangeListeningActivityLocationCallback(LocationChangeListeningActivity activity) {
    this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
}
```

My question is, how can we provide the callback in this case?

Comment: I've tried `public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationEngineCallback` and then just override the methods. Finally set the request from the engine likewise `locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, this, getMainLooper());` but I'm not sure, whether it is the solution?

Comment: Why don't you just use the LocationProvider Android offers? It seems that you do not display it on a Mapbox map. The Android LocationProvider works flawlessly in a Foreground service: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider
(if you do not specify a different LocationProvider, Mapbox will also make use of the Android LocationProvider under the hood)

Comment: I display it on the Mapbox map, when the user turns on his screen. The FusedLocationProvider from Mapbox is more compact, acts better on the phone performance and you save boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it (not sure whether it's the most efficient way but if I find another one, the post will be updated). The class, which extends the `Service` class needs just to implement the `LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineRequest>` like so:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult>{
...
}
```

After that, we just set the requesting of the location and retrieving the lastLocation to the current instance(this):

```
locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, this, getMainLooper());
locationEngine.getLastLocation(this);
```

And in the overridden methods declare the internal logic:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
    //Handle Success
}

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    //Handle Failure
}
```

Of course, don't forget to stop the updates and remove the `LocationEngine` after stopping the service:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    locationEngine = null;
}
```